# Using Java PriorityQueue in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, priority-queue

I need a min-heap in Matlab and I'm trying to use Java's PriorityQueue. I'm stuck on how to supply the Comparator.
So far I have initialized the PriorityQueue and can add one value-index pair to it:

```
>> q = java.util.PriorityQueue
q =
[]
>> q.add({1,3})
ans =
     1
```

The problem occurs when I try to add more data:

```
>> q.add({2,4})
??? Java exception occurred: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(Unknown Source)
```

From [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/293430) post, I see that I need to supply a Comparator function, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I suspect you have to write the comparator function in Java and compile it separately.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that is the way to do it. I'm not that fluent in Java so I've looked for other solutions and found an entry on the file exchange (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24238-priority-queue-mexc) that does what I need, although it crashes rather ungracefully if try to push something from an empty queue.

Answer (score 1):

Priority queues need to either contain objects that implement Comparable, or you need to pass in a Comparator function at construction time.

There isn't a way currently in MATLAB to either implement Java interfaces with MATLAB code, or supply literal Java code.

So you'd have to follow @nibot's suggestion and make a small .jar file containing a class implementing Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer assuming you can use non-negative floating values and integer indices. The idea is to stringy the pair and use that as the comparable object in the java queue.

```matlab
q = java.util.PriorityQueue;
q.add(encode(1.2,4));
q.add(encode(1.1,8));
q.add(encode(8.0,1));
q.add(encode(1e-7,0));

% Pop and print
while ~q.isEmpty()
  [value,index] = decode(q.remove());
  fprintf('%g,%d\n',value,index)
end

function u = encode(value,index)
  % value should be non-negative
  % index should be an integer
  u = sprintf('%010d,%d',uint64(java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits(value)),index);
end
function [value,index] = decode(u)
  value_index = sscanf(u,'%d,%d',2);
  value = java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat(value_index(1));
  index = value_index(2);
end
```

On a quick and dirty test, pushing and then popping 10000 random floats takes 0.5secs compared to pushing then popping 10000 (random float, index) pairs takes 0.75secs. There's overhead, but maybe not a killer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

q = java.util.PriorityQueue();
for i=1:10
q.add(i);
end
disp(q)
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.