# Is there any way to implement min/max queue?

Tags: matlab

Currently, I am running a script using sort to select k minimums but it's pretty slow when data is large.

So I think I need to select only k rows based on a certain column of given matrix with min/max queue. Is there any way to do that in matlab?

Comment: I understand downvote can occur but could you at least comment so I can know what is wrong with my question?

Comment: You could have a look at implementing  some of the efficient algorithms outlined here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm. To actually achieve performance that exceeds the MATLAB `sort` function you'd probably have to produce an optimised MEX function, as an m-file solution is typically much slower than compiled code. You should also post your existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about finding `M` minimum values one after the other and removing the found minimum values after each iteration, but it's slower, try my benchmark:

```
elements = 1e4;
runs = 20;
numMin = 30;
dat = rand(elements, 1);

tic
for i = 1:runs
    d = sort(dat);
    mins1 = d(1:numMin);
end
t1 = toc/runs

tic
for i = 1:runs
    mins2 = zeros(numMin, 1);
    d = dat;
    for j = 1:numMin
        [val, idx] = min(d);
        mins2(j) = val;
        d(idx) = [];
    end
end
t2 = toc/runs

isequal(mins1, mins2)
```

Comment: yes they really could, mex files are often much faster than buil-in m-scripts because they need to be interpreted

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of something like a priority queue that is native to matlab.  There's a 
[mex-file implementation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24238-priority-queue-mexc++) of one on the Matlab file exchange, or apparently you do it with Java - see [this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454364/using-java-priorityqueue-in-matlab) and [this question on the Matlab forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/293430).

That will only help you a lot if you frequently have to insert and remove elements of your list. If you can put all your elements in at one time and just sort at the end, that might be just as fast as using a priority queue.  It probably depends on the details of what you're doing.